# Rails adding a random path to URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, url, redirect

So when the link to my website is clicked (not typed), rails app adds paths to url like

```
http://www.drolle.co/NgOLZ/posts/187
```

the "NgOLZ" is added and it's unique every time.
I have no idea why. Here's my code:

```
  # Define root URL
  root 'pages#index'
  resources :posts do

   resources :comments do
     member do
      put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
     end
     resources :replies do
       member do
        put "like", to: "replies#upvote" 
        put "dislike", to: "replies#downvote"
       end
     end
   end

   member do
     put "like", to: "posts#upvote"  
     put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote" 
     put "report", to: "posts#report"
   end

  end
```

And in the logs

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/NgOLZ/posts/187"
```

the extra letters are added even with http://drolle.co
I did have an error with a missing nodejs module so I added universalify, may be this has to do with it? I don't really know.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: What does the link that's being clicked look like?

Comment: Works for me... http://www.drolle.co/posts/184

Comment: @RonanLouarn maybe its a reddit error. Some reddit posts have wrong url   Aliens inspecting humans like..

https://www.reddit.com/r/youdontsurf/comments/70noee/aliens_inspecting_humans_like/